# Android edittext with shadow like cardview

Tags: java, android

I have tried to implement edittext with shadow like the https://www.google.com.gh/imghp using this layerd xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- most important is order of layers -->

<!-- Bottom right side 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="3px"
    android:left="3px"
    android:right="3px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

.but have not succeded. can anyone place help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this into layer-list drawable file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- most important is order of layers -->

<!-- Bottom right side 2dp Shadow -->
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#BEBEBE" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="3px" android:right="3px" android:top="3px" android:left="3px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: thank you but doe not give me that look and behavoir of the about link